# ShuffleSplit of Sklearn issue

Tags: python, split, sklearn-pandas, autoencoder

I have a data set named `df_noyau_yes` and I want to apply a ShuffleSplit to split it into train and test sets to train an autoencoder.

The problem is that this functions returns indices of the shuffled data, I tried to extract the data of these indices to feed them to the autoencoder but it dosen't work, it shows me an error `KeyError 223`

Here is the code:

```
rs = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=2, test_size=.25, random_state=0)
rs.get_n_splits(df_noyau_yes)

for train_index, test_index in rs.split(df_noyau_yes):
   print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
   #X_train, X_test = df_noyau_yes[train_index], df_noyau_yes[test_index]
x_train=[]
for x in train_index:
    x_train = np.append(x_train, df_noyau_yes[x])
    print(x_train)

print("training set",x_train)
```

Is there any solution for that ??

Comment: Is df_noyau_yes a pandas Dataframe? If yes, then you cannot access the samples by simple indexing as you are doing here.

Comment: yes it's a pandas Dataframe. So how can I do it ?

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

For selection a dataframe values by index of rows and columns, `iloc` is used.

From [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position):

> The .iloc attribute is the primary access method. The following are
>   valid inputs:
>
> ```
> An integer e.g. 5
> A list or array of integers [4, 3, 0]
> A slice object with ints 1:7
> A boolean array
> A callable, see Selection By Callable
> ```

So you can simply provide your `train_index`, `test_index` to get the appropriate arrays.

```
x_train = df_noyau_yes.iloc[train_index].copy()
x_test = df_noyau_yes.iloc[test_index].copy()
```

I am using `copy()` here as an extra precaution. Because if you dont use `copy()`, and try to change a value in x_train or x_test, a warning is thrown.

Comment: I know 'iloc' method but I need to try something that shuffle the data: something dynamic not static.

Comment: @Mari Thats what the ShuffleSplit is doing here. Please explain your use case in detail.